# Querying ASCII columns with Unicode search strings yields "Illegal mix of collations"

Tags: sql, mysql, collation

**== Given ==**

```
// MariaDB 11 system

> show variables like '%coll%';
+----------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value                  |
+----------------------+------------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb3_general_ci     |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |
+----------------------+------------------------+

> CREATE TABLE `users` (`email` VARCHAR(80) CHARACTER SET ascii PRIMARY KEY) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

email addresses can at best be ASCII, so that seems right. Right?

**== Input trigger ==**

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='a@üni.code';
```

**== Observed ==**

```
ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (ascii_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb3_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

**== Expected to see ==**

Don't raise an error, just return zero rows. `a@üni.code` would never match users.email anyway because the column just could not store it in the first place.

(Or does it? It seems possible to `insert into users values (_ascii'a@üni.code');` o_O)

**== Alternatives tried ==**

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONVERT(email USING utf8)='a@üni.code';
```

-> works, but indexed search is out the door (as per DESCRIBE SELECT)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=_ascii'a@üni.code';
```

-> there ought to be downsides, I just don't them yet.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=CONVERT('a@üni.code' USING ascii);
```

-> the conversion result is `a@?nicode.com`, which *could* lead to a row returned that is not anticipated. (Somehow, if CONVERT could return NULL instead, that'd be helpful.)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email COLLATE utf8_general_ci = 'a@üni.code';
```

-> yields `COLLATION 'utf8mb3_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'ascii'`, which means nothing to me / does not provide an angle to remedy the invalidness.

ASCII is valid UTF-8, so using a UTF collation (sorting function?) on ASCII keys should be ok, shouldn't they...

Comment: I’m not clear why you are specifying character sets. Why not just leave everything as utf8 and then you won’t have any issues? What benefit do you think you are getting specifying the character set on a single column?

Comment: Since the literal string is not in ASCII (because of u-diaeresis, ü), something has to give.

Comment: specify the collation in your query see: https://dbfiddle.uk/vJhpVH9q You make life more difficult when you start adding specific collations to columns - i.e. you  need to also include those decisions into all downstream code